# geokettle shapefile input transformation not generation row numbers

Tags: transformation, shapefile, geokettle

Does anyone know why, on GeoKettle, the 'Shapefile File Input Step' is not generating the row number?
How can I do a around? With the 'Add Sequence' step?

This is all happening on a transformation.

Tks

Comment: It seems there is a bug on the step 'Shapefile File Input' on transformations. Using other inputs that have the same option 'Add rownr?' it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some amount of digging on the inners of this, what I came out with was that this is simply a bug on the implementation of the step "Shapefile File Input". I did not find this on other inputs that generate the same row number...

The GeoKettle version is 2.5 as of this answer and in turns is based on Pentaho Kettle version 3.2...